Tailwind utilities void error that doesn't go away
I'm developing a Next.js app. I was trying to mess with the styling and at the end I got this weird void error...
User
Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/globals.css
 GET /portraits 500 in 17242ms
 ⨯ ./src/app/globals.css:4:1
Module not found: Can't resolve './${props.imgInactive}'

Here's the issue though... line 4 is empty - global.css is default. All changes I made I ultimately reverted. What's funnier, deleting @tailwind utilities fixes the issue, but breaks Tailwind (duh).
Already tried deleting all node modules, clearing cache etc.

Does this answer your question? Why is there an error when passing an object consisting of a file path to the image and setting in bg-[url()] tailwindcss?

It seems like you may have some markup in your project like:
<div className={`… bg-[url(./${props.imgInactive})] …`}>

As per the documentation:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
Don’t construct class names dynamically
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
Always use complete class names
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>


Thus, with regards to the error, Tailwind interprets the class bg-[url(${props.imgInactive})] literally:
.bg-\[url\(\$\{props\.imgInactive\}\)\] {
  background-image: url(${props.imgInactive});
}

and as the error suggests, Next cannot find this file named ${props.imgInactive} literally.
To work around this, consider using the style attribute:
<div … style={{ backgroundImage: `url(./${props.imgInactive})` }}>

